# Saving a file using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to save a file to another directory which user selects from one directory. I know that `JFileChooser` can be use to select a file. But instead of using any output streams kind of things is there any way to move a file from one location to another in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Only and only if they are on the **same** local disk file system, you can use [`File#renameTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) for this.

```
File sourceFile = createItSomehow();
File targetFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

boolean renamed = sourceFile.renameTo(targetFile);

if (!renamed) {
    // Well, perhaps they are not on the same disk?
}
```

For all other cases, you're really better off by just streaming it. See also the linked javadoc:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.